# Xamarin android fail to load images

Tags: android, xamarin

I am a new developer of Xamarin. I am trying to build a simple button image and the problem is that **the image, it didn't appear** in my phone.
I use also for debug xamarin live from VS2017 and my phone.
When I built and run live there are no warnings or errors. So is difficult to look what is wrong.

What I did so far:

I checked the images in Android folder resources and checked if icons have the right dimensions.

I do the steps: clean solution, rebuilt solution, built solution and restart VS2017

App.xaml.cs:

```
public App ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="50">

        <Button Text="Hello" BackgroundColor="Wheat" BorderRadius="20" TextColor="Black">
            <Button.Image>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource" Android="icon.png"/>
            </Button.Image>
        </Button>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Button Text="Left" BackgroundColor="IndianRed" BorderRadius="22" TextColor="Black">
                    <Button.Image>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource" Android="icon.png"/>
                    </Button.Image>
                </Button>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Button Text="Right" BackgroundColor="IndianRed" BorderRadius="22" TextColor="Black">
                    <Button.Image>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource" Android="icon.png"/>
                    </Button.Image>
                </Button>

            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

I load the default icon.png and I checked hdpi(72x72), mdpi(48x48),xhdpi(96x96),xxhdpi(144x144),xxxhdpi(192x192) have the right dimensions.

I saw the buttons in right position with a text inside but with no image. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your xaml:

```
<Button Image="icon.png" Text="Hello" BackgroundColor="Wheat" BorderRadius="20" TextColor="Black"/>
```

Or in your code:

```
yourButton.Image = "icon.png";
```

or

```
yourButton.Image = ImageSource.FromFile("icon.png");
```

Comment: No it is the same. I saw that xamarin live has a problem because In xamarin.forms preview I can saw the icons.

Comment: Yes, on my device works. Only in Xamarin live it didn't. I don't know why.

Comment: With the code in your question, it was working in Xamarin Live?

Comment: Not mine and not yours in Xamarin Live only on my physical device and xamarin forms preview.